# How to share .resx files between projects in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization, .net-4.7.1

Currently, we have a number of .NET Framework 4.7.1 VB projects (each under a solution of its own) that have the same global resources for language translations:

```
project1.vbproj
    App_GlobalResources
        module1.resx
        module1.en.resx
        module1.de.resx
        module2.resx
        module2.en.resx
        module2.de.resx
        …
        modulen.resx
        modulen.en.resx
        modulen.de.resx
project2.vbproj
    App_GlobalResources
        module1.resx
        module1.en.resx
        module1.de.resx
        module2.resx
        module2.en.resx
        module2.de.resx
        …
        modulen.resx
        modulen.en.resx
        modulen.de.resx
…
projectm.vbproj
    App_GlobalResources
        module1.resx
        module1.en.resx
        module1.de.resx
        module2.resx
        module2.en.resx
        module2.de.resx
        …
        modulen.resx
        modulen.en.resx
        modulen.de.resx
```

Then we access the resources with the usual notation, e.g., in `.ascx` files:

```
<%=Resources.module1.text1%>
```

Is it possible to get rid of the file duplication? As an example, put `module1.resx` to a shared project and then let all projects refer to that shared project?

There is no need to be able to modify the `.resx` files without re-compilation, we just want to simplify the source code control.

We would like to keep the current `.resx` files untouched.

We can modify the references to the resources (`Resources.module1.text1`) to something else if that is necessary and the change is a simple one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly possible. You may follow the following steps:

1. Create a new class-library project called `CommonResources`.
2. Add all the resources files (including localized one) to it.
3. Make sure you set the Access Modifier of each resource file to `Public`.

   [image: CommonResources project demo]
4. Build the project.
5. In each one of your main projects, add a reference to the main assembly of the CommonResources project (`CommonResources.dll`).

   [image: Adding a reference]
6. To access a resource, simply use something like:

   ```
   CommonResources.Module1.Foo
   CommonResources.Module2.Bar
   ```

**See it in action:**

[image: Using shared resources]

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer! However, if I add `CommonResources` as a VB project, I need to use `CommonResources.My.Resources.Module1.Foo`. Is it possible to remove `My.Resources` somehow? If `CommonResources`is a C# project, I am not able to refer to `CommonResources` for some reason (?) I thought it should work.

Comment: @masa _"Is it possible to remove My.Resources somehow?"_ Yes, do not add the resource files under `My Project`. Instead, add them in the root directory of your project as shown in the first screenshot. _"If `CommonResources` is a C# project, I am not able to refer to `CommonResources` for some reason"_ What you see in the first screenshot is actually a C# project. Again, add the resx files in the root directory  and make sure the access modifier is set to `Public`.

Comment: In both cases, the `.resx` files were already in the root directory. For the VB project, I needed to clear the Custom Tool Namespace for the `.resx` file, and it started working. I still do not know, why the C# project is not working.